# IPv6 Firewall Rules

Tags: iptables, firewall, linux-networking, ipv6

I have a DigitalOcean droplet which is used for a few things, primarily as a web host and SMTP server. I have recently started dabbling in IPv6 and have successfully configured it on the VPS; `ping6` works great to google.com, etc. The local LAN network is configured with IPv6 via slaac and can ping and connect to the DO droplet without issue.

Where I’m running into issues is with setting up `ip6tables`. I did a basic configuration which only allows SSH, Web, and SMTP, but after adding the rules, everything stops being able to connect to the VPS over IPv6. As soon as I flush the tables, it’s fine. It also seems that if I setup a connection (like web or ssh) before adding the rules, the connections work after the rules are added,  it only for a little bit. I’m not sure what’s blocking the connections at this point, any guidance would be helpful.

```
ip6tables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1880  121K ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    2   136 ACCEPT     all      lo     *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    1    84 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:25
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:80
    1    80 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:587
  774 55932 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 2537  168K ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
```

---

**UPDATE**: Added a log statement to capture some logs, then went ahead and tried to SSH from a client that I know wouldn't work. It wouldn't connect and I gave up after waiting maybe 10-seconds.

```
Mar 29 08:57:55 cloud kernel: [170352.518576] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=33:33:ff:e2:40:01:84:b5:9c:f9:18:30:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001:ffe2:4001 LEN=72 TC=192 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=135 CODE=0 
Mar 29 08:57:56 cloud kernel: [170353.518091] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=33:33:ff:e2:40:01:84:b5:9c:f9:18:30:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001:ffe2:4001 LEN=72 TC=192 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=135 CODE=0 
Mar 29 08:57:57 cloud kernel: [170354.517936] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=33:33:ff:e2:40:01:84:b5:9c:f9:18:30:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001:ffe2:4001 LEN=72 TC=192 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=135 CODE=0 
Mar 29 08:57:59 cloud kernel: [170356.517573] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=33:33:ff:e2:40:01:84:b5:9c:f9:18:30:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001:ffe2:4001 LEN=72 TC=192 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=135 CODE=0
```

Why is the SRC `fe80::1`? That's definitely not the source IP from where I'm connecting from (it's abreviated prefix is `2600:1700`). Also, the DST is `ff02::1:ffe2:4001` which does appear to be configured on the interface as well:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:01:3a:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 104.236.XXX.XXX/18 brd 104.236.XXX.XXX scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2604:a880:800:XXXX::YYYY:4001/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::601:3aff:fe85:dd01/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

ip -6 route
2604:a880:800:10::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev tap0 proto kernel metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256  pref medium
default via 2604:a880:800:XXXX::1 dev eth0 metric 1024  pref medium
```

---

As requested, `ip6tables-save`

```
ip6tables-save
# Generated by ip6tables-save v1.6.0 on Thu Mar 29 09:03:33 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j LOG
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Mar 29 09:03:33 2018
```

Comment: As with most ip(6)tables debugging, try adding a logging rule just before your drop rule and see what is matching.

Comment: `ip6tables-save` output might be more informative...

Comment: What you are seeing is the Neighbor Discovery. The `ff02::1:ffe2:4001` destination address is the solicited node multicast address to which the ND is sent. The `fe80::/10` address is the link-local address. IPv6 makes heavy use of multicast because there is no broadcast, and many things use the link-local addresses on the local LAN. You will need to allow such things in your rules.

Comment: @RonMaupin Interesting. I pulled up `tcpdump` and it looks like it's asking who has the address that's configured on the eth0 interface. `09:09:39.980123 IP6 fe80::1 > ff02::1:ffe2:4001: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2604:a880:800:XX::YY:4001, length 32`

Comment: That' what I was saying. Since IPv6 doesn't have broadcast, it cannot use ARP. You must have a solicited node multicast address for every address assigned to the interface. It is based on the last 24 bits of the address, so if you have all the addresses with the same last 24 bits, you only need the one solicited node multicast address. You must also allow an `fe80::/10` addressing. That is only on the local link (it cannot be routed), so it should be safe.

Comment: @RonMaupin Wow. That was easy. I just added an accept all for ICMPv6 and now it's working! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, unlike ICMP for IPv4, ICMPv6 is very important, and you need to allow just about everything with ICMPv6. There are very few things in ICMPv6 that you can safely block. See _[RFC 4890, Recommendations for Filtering ICMPv6 Messages in Firewalls](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4890)_ for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPv6 nodes all have link-local addresses, which are in the `fe80::/10` network. Nodes will use the link-local addressing for various things that remain on the local link (it cannot be routed), so you must allow that addressing in your rules.

IPv6 doesn't have broadcast, so it makes heavy use of multicast. Nodes will have multiple unicast/anycast addresses on an interface, and a node must subscribe to the solicited-node multicast address for each of those addresses. The solicited-node multicast address is based on the last 24 bits of the unicast address, so if all your unicast/multicast addresses have the same last 24 bits, then you will only have one solicited-node multicast group for the interface (this is the ideal).

IPv6 Neighbor Discover uses the solicited-node multicast address. Since IPv6 doesn't have broadcast, ARP is not used to relate the layer-2 address to the layer-3 address. IPv6 uses ND for that, and that uses the solicited-node multicast address.